# Jmeter - incorrect sample time

Tags: jmeter

I have a scenario wherein i have to export the values(the details of a group of people) from a webpage either in CVS or PDF format in my desktop. The response was success When i recorded this scenario in jmeter. When i added recorded samplers in the thread group and ran them, i received success response with 302 response code. But the sample time is very less when compared with F12 time(manually captured it using F12 developer tool).

It was a POST request when i recorded it. In the results it was showing 3 different child samples out of that 1 is POST and the remaining 2 are GET requests. And 1 additional request with blank request.

The below is the structure:

1 /WebPages/Common/abc.aspx?mhsghgsjfgjsdg
 -child1 (POST request)
 -child2(GET request)
 -child3(GET request)
1 /WebPages/Common/abc.aspx?mhsghgsjfgjsdg (blank request)

It's a C# application. Even for some other requests i am getting 302 response code with correct sample time. So i have no issues with those samples.

Could someone assist me to find out what could be the issue for the incorrect sample time? and how can i resolve it to get the correct sample time?

Appreciate your inputs or resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you are not handling so called "embedded resources". Almost each HTML page contains some images, styles, scripts, fonts, etc.

In the "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) configuration element tick:

- Retrieve All Embedded Resources
- Parallel Downloads

[image: JMeter HTTP Request Defaults]

This way you will "tell" all JMeter [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers to download images, scripts, styles, etc. like browsers do therefore you should start getting comparable response time.

For more information on tuning JMeter so your test would be more realistic check out [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) guide.